# Why is the integral of $1/x$ not $\ln|ax|$?

Tags: integration

Wouldn't any non-zero constant $a$ cause the derivative of $\ln|ax|$ to simply be $1/x$? So shouldn't the integral of $1/x$ include the constant $a$? I am probably missing something basic here, thanks!

(EDIT: I just realized as I posted that with logarithm rules this $a$ value just goes to the $+C$ constant from integrating, so got!)

Comment: The a's cancel out. Try chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

because of:

$$ \dfrac{ d \log ax }{dx} = \frac{ (ax)' }{ax} = \frac{a}{ax} = \frac{1}{x } $$

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. My question was why the anti-derivative didn't include an a, BECAUSE they cancel out. But I figured it it's part of the plus C.

Comment: The constant of integration $C$ eats it out because remember $\log(ax) = \log a + \log x $ and $\log a $ is a constant